# emacs magit switch to quick mode

Tags: git, emacs, magit

I have a merge conflict. I want to resolve it, and I use `magit-ediff-resolve`. I am presented with the correct list of files to merge (the ones that have conflicts), and then Emacs splits in three correctly.

I have, however, to edit the `C` buffer (the one down) manually.

How can I switch to the quick mode (the mode that allows using `n`, `p`, `a` and `b` commands) ?

**Note** : When I use `git mergetool` from the command line, I can merge into quick mode properly, but in the console only.

Comment: Does v2 still do that? If not, then please delete this. If it does, then please provide more details. Is the problem that the wrong buffer is selected? If so, you can select the control buffer manually (`C-x o`) and then you can use these commands (is that what you mean by "quick mode"?).

Comment: @tarsius not sure. I will test as soon as I have a conflict.